# Indexing the max elements in a multidimensional tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to index the maximum elements along the last dimension in a multidimensional tensor. For example, say I have a tensor

```
A = torch.randn((5, 2, 3))
_, idx = torch.max(A, dim=2)
```

Here idx stores the maximum indices, which may look something like

```
>>>> A
tensor([[[ 1.0503,  0.4448,  1.8663],
     [ 0.8627,  0.0685,  1.4241]],

    [[ 1.2924,  0.2456,  0.1764],
     [ 1.3777,  0.9401,  1.4637]],

    [[ 0.5235,  0.4550,  0.2476],
     [ 0.7823,  0.3004,  0.7792]],

    [[ 1.9384,  0.3291,  0.7914],
     [ 0.5211,  0.1320,  0.6330]],

    [[ 0.3292,  0.9086,  0.0078],
     [ 1.3612,  0.0610,  0.4023]]])
>>>> idx
tensor([[ 2,  2],
    [ 0,  2],
    [ 0,  0],
    [ 0,  2],
    [ 1,  0]])
```

I want to be able to access these indices and assign to another tensor based on them. Meaning I want to be able to do

```
B = torch.new_zeros(A.size())
B[idx] = A[idx]
```

where B is 0 everywhere except where A is maximum along the last dimension. That is B should store

```
>>>>B
tensor([[[ 0,  0,  1.8663],
     [ 0,  0,  1.4241]],

    [[ 1.2924,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  1.4637]],

    [[ 0.5235,  0,  0],
     [ 0.7823,  0,  0]],

    [[ 1.9384,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0.6330]],

    [[ 0,  0.9086,  0],
     [ 1.3612,  0,  0]]])
```

This is proving to be much more difficult than I expected, as the idx does not index the array A properly. Thus far I have been unable to find a vectorized solution to use idx to index A.

Is there a good vectorized way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ugly hackaround is to create a binary mask out of `idx` and use it to index the arrays. The basic code looks like this:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)

A = torch.randn((5, 2, 3))
_, idx = torch.max(A, dim=2)

mask = torch.arange(A.size(2)).reshape(1, 1, -1) == idx.unsqueeze(2)
B = torch.zeros_like(A)
B[mask] = A[mask]
print(A)
print(B)
```

The trick is that `torch.arange(A.size(2))` enumerates the possible values in `idx` and `mask` is nonzero in places where they equal the `idx`. Remarks:

1. If you really discard the first output of `torch.max`, you can use [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.argmax) instead.
2. I assume that this is a minimal example of some wider problem, but be aware that you are currently reinventing [`torch.nn.functional.max_pool3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.argmax) with kernel of size `(1, 1, 3)`.
3. Also, be aware that in-place modification of tensors with masked assignment can cause issues with autograd, so you may want to use `torch.where` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691156/cant-find-the-inplace-operation-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-compu/53692802#53692802).

I would expect that somebody comes up with a cleaner solution (avoiding the intermedia allocation of the `mask` array), likely making use of [`torch.index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.index_select), but I can't get it to work right now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`torch.meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.meshgrid) to create an index tuple:

```
>>> index_tuple = torch.meshgrid([torch.arange(x) for x in A.size()[:-1]]) + (idx,)
>>> B = torch.zeros_like(A)
>>> B[index_tuple] = A[index_tuple]
```

Note that you can also mimic `meshgrid` via (for the specific case of 3D):

```
>>> index_tuple = (
...     torch.arange(A.size(0))[:, None],
...     torch.arange(A.size(1))[None, :],
...     idx
... )
```

---

**Bit more explanation:**
  We will have the indices something like this:

```
In [173]: idx 
Out[173]: 
tensor([[2, 1],
        [2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 2]])
```

From this, we want to go to three indices (since our tensor is 3D, we need three numbers to retrieve each element). Basically we want to build a grid in the first two dimensions, as shown below. (And that's why we use meshgrid).

```
In [174]: A[0, 0, 2], A[0, 1, 1]  
Out[174]: (tensor(0.6288), tensor(-0.3070))

In [175]: A[1, 0, 2], A[1, 1, 0]  
Out[175]: (tensor(1.7085), tensor(0.7818))

In [176]: A[2, 0, 2], A[2, 1, 1]  
Out[176]: (tensor(0.4823), tensor(1.1199))

In [177]: A[3, 0, 2], A[3, 1, 2]    
Out[177]: (tensor(1.6903), tensor(1.0800))

In [178]: A[4, 0, 2], A[4, 1, 2]          
Out[178]: (tensor(0.9138), tensor(0.1779))
```

In the above 5 lines, the first two numbers in the indices are basically the grid that we build using meshgrid and the third number is coming from `idx`.

i.e. the first two numbers form a grid.

```
 (0, 0) (0, 1)
 (1, 0) (1, 1)
 (2, 0) (2, 1)
 (3, 0) (3, 1)
 (4, 0) (4, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! But what if the idx is the 2nd dimension instead of the last one?

Answer (score 0):

could use torch.scatter [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_)

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn(4,2,3)
>>> a
tensor([[[ 0.1583,  0.1102, -0.8188],
         [ 0.6328, -1.9169, -0.5596]],

        [[ 0.5335,  0.4069,  0.8403],
         [-1.2537,  0.9868, -0.4947]],

        [[-1.2830,  0.4386, -0.0107],
         [ 1.3384,  0.5651,  0.2877]],

        [[-0.0334, -1.0619, -0.1144],
         [ 0.1954, -0.7371,  1.7001]]])
>>> ind = torch.max(a,1,keepdims=True)[1]
>>> ind
tensor([[[1, 0, 1]],

        [[0, 1, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1]],

        [[1, 1, 1]]])
>>> torch.zeros_like(a).scatter(1,ind,a)
tensor([[[ 0.0000,  0.1102,  0.0000],
         [ 0.1583,  0.0000, -0.8188]],

        [[ 0.5335,  0.0000,  0.8403],
         [ 0.0000,  0.4069,  0.0000]],

        [[ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [-1.2830,  0.4386, -0.0107]],

        [[ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [-0.0334, -1.0619, -0.1144]]])
```