# Can't fix torch autograd runtime error: UNet inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, unet-neural-network

I can't fix the runtime error "one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation.

I know, that if I comment out `loss.backward()` the code will run, but I don't get in which order should I call the functions to avoid this error

When I call it my wrapper with Resnet50 I don't experience any problems, but with Unet the RuntimeError occurs

```
    for i, (x, y) in batch_iter:
        with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True):
            input, target = x.to(self.device), y.to(self.device)

            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            if self.box_training:
                out = self.model(input)
            else:
                out = self.model(input).clamp(0,1)
            
            loss = self.criterion(out, target)                
            loss_value = loss.item()
            train_losses.append(loss_value)
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()

            batch_iter.set_description(f'Training: (loss {loss_value:.4f})')

    self.training_loss.append(np.mean(train_losses))
    self.learning_rate.append(self.optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])
```

As the comments pointed out, I should provide a model

And by looking at it, I actually found what was the problem:

```
model = UNet(in_channels=1,
         num_encoding_blocks = 6,
         out_classes = 1,
         padding=1,
         dimensions = 2,
         out_channels_first_layer = 32,
         normalization = None,
         pooling_type = 'max',
         upsampling_type = 'conv',
         preactivation = False,
         #residual = True,
         padding_mode = 'zeros',
         activation = 'ReLU',
         initial_dilation = None,
         dropout = 0,
         monte_carlo_dropout = 0
        )
```

It is `residual = True` which I has commented out. I will look into the docs, what is going on. Maybe if you have an idea, you can enlighten me

Comment: As you're saying the problem is in the model apparently so you need to provide it to get help. Of course removing `backward()` removes the problem, because it is the function triggering the issue :)

Comment: This error is caused by an in-place operation in the forward computation of your model, i.e. the `self.model.forward` method. Replace that operation with the out-of-place version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't find the inplace operation: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691156/cant-find-the-inplace-operation-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-compu)

Comment: I use UNet model, so I do not define a forward method. What could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

It looks like the UNet library you are using includes a `+=` (in-place tensor addition) [in the residual branch of the encoder](https://github.com/fepegar/unet/blob/master/unet/encoding.py#L146):

```py
if self.residual:
    connection = self.conv_residual(x)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x += connection # <------- !!!
```

In-place operations like `+=` may overwrite information that is needed for gradient computation during `loss.backward()`. PyTorch detects when this necessary information has been overwritten, and complains.

**Fix:**

If you want to train this network with `residual` enabled, you would need to replace this `+=` with a not-in-place add:

```py
if self.residual:
    connection = self.conv_residual(x)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = x + connection # <-------
```

A similar edit is needed in the [decoder](https://github.com/fepegar/unet/blob/master/unet/decoding.py#L136). If you installed this `unet` library via `pip`, you would want to download it directly from [github](https://github.com/fepegar/unet) instead so you can make these edits (and uninstall the `pip` version to avoid confusion).

For more information about why in-place operations can cause problems, see [this blog post](https://lernapparat.de/pytorch-inplace) or [this section of the PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd).