# Can not find the inplace operation about "one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation"

Tags: python, pytorch

```
dataset = Data(params)
detector = Detector(params)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(detector.parameters(), lr=params['learning_rate'])

Loss = []  
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
for epoch in range(params['maxEpoch']):
    y, h_a, h_b, plus, hTy, hTh = dataset.generate()
    x_ = detector(hTy, hTh)

    loss = 0.0
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for _ in range(1, params['DetNet_layer']):
        loss += criterion(x_[:,:,_], torch.from_numpy(plus).to(torch.double)) * math.log(_)

    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()

    Loss.append(loss.item())
```

Above is my main.py file, the error happen in loss.backward(). And the class Detetor is:

```
def forward(self, HTy, HTH):
    HTy_torch = torch.from_numpy(HTy).unsqueeze(1)
    HTH_torch = torch.from_numpy(HTH).unsqueeze(1)

    x_torch = torch.from_numpy(np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1, self.L)))
    v_torch = torch.from_numpy(np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1, self.L)))

    for i in range(1, self.L):
        x_tmp, v_tmp = self.layers[i](HTy_torch, HTH_torch, x_torch[:, :, i-1], v_torch[:, :, i-1])
        x_torch[:, :, i] = x_tmp
        v_torch[:, :, i] = v_tmp

    return x_torch
```

Is the slide operation [:,:,i] make the inplace operation?

If so, how can I modify it?

I have try 'retain_graph=True' in function loss.backword.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691156/cant-find-the-inplace-operation-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-compu) has a lot of information, including links to debugging help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the use of `loss +=`. Try something like

```py
losses = []
for _ in range(1, params['DetNet_layer']):
    losses.append(criterion(x_[:,:,_], torch.from_numpy(plus).to(torch.double)) * math.log(_))
loss = torch.cat(losses).sum()
```

Also you probably want to use a float rather than a double there.